# Uninitialized constant when using nested attributes on STI subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes, sti

I have a class/model called User which (using Single table inheritance) has a subclass called Student (among others)

Student has a 'has_one' association with 'HomeAddress' which is a subclass of 'Place'

My model set up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < User
    has_one :home_address, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_address
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class HomeAddress < Place
    belongs_to :student
end
```

In my Students controller, I'm trying to create a new Student and associated HomeAddress to pass through to my view:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

def new

@student = Student.new
@student.build_home_address

end
```

however, I get an error:

```
:uninitialized constant Student::HomeAddress
```

This issue is clearly with the line *@student.build_home_address* but I don't understand why it's causing this error. I've checked all of naming conventions (i.e. models, controllers, associations) and have other nested attributes relationships working in my app. Perhaps there is an issues with having nested attributes for an STI subclass? (i.e. HomeAddress)

Let me know if you would like to see any other code.
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you should do this `has_one :student, :dependent => :destroy` instead of `has_one :home_address, :dependent => :destroy`

Comment: try replace `belongs_to :student` to `belongs_to :user` just for check